# Does Racket support internal "define"?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm new to functional language and I'm doing SICP programming assignments using Racket.

Below is a snippet of code, and Racket informs me that `define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 5 extra parts`, in line 5 (`(define (y k)`):

```
(define (simpson f a b n)

 (define h (/ (- b a) n))

 (define (y k)
  (f (+ a (* k h))))

 (define (factor k)
  (cond ((or (= k 0) (= k n))
         1)
   ((odd? k)
    4)
   (else
    2)))

 (define (term k)
  (* (factor k)
   (y k)))

 (define (next k)
  (+ k 1))

(if (not (even? n))
 (error "n can't be odd")
 (* (/ h 3)
  (sum term (exact->inexact a) next n))))
```

I guess this problem is related to the language settings, but I already use "advanced" option.

Anybody know how to configure Racket properly, or internal "define" is not supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, it's as you say: internal `define`s are not supported by the Advanced language. For working with the SICP exercises, I've been told it's best to use the `neil/sicp` package: [instructions for using this are detailed here](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/neil/sicp.plt/1/17/planet-docs/sicp/index.html#%28part._installation%29).

However, even the standard Racket language (`#lang racket`) will support internal `define`s without problems.

Comment: Chris is right, internal define is supported both in #lang racket and in neil/sicp. If you prefer to use the Advanced teaching language (the stepper is a great tool!) then you can make internal aka local definitions using `local`. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html?q=local#(form._((lib._lang/htdp-advanced..rkt)._local))